# How to change substring style in react native

Tags: react-native

I have some text to show the user and I want to change style for some indiviual part of string.If the text is between "**" must have bold style.For example

```
{
        title: 'Food inside a Bowl', url: 'https://www.myvarco.com/varco-images/screen-3.png',
        description: "Lorem Ipsum is **simply dummy** text of the printing and **typesetting industry**.",
        id: 2
},
```

How I can achieve this in react native

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom component like below I've added the check for start ** you can change the condition in anyway you want.

```
const CustomText = (props) => {
 const arr = props.text.split(' ');
  const reducer = (acc, cur, index) => {
    let previousVal = acc[acc.length - 1];
    if (
      previousVal &&
      previousVal.startsWith('**') &&
      !previousVal.endsWith('**')
    ) {
      acc[acc.length - 1] = previousVal + ' ' + cur;
    } else {
      acc.push(cur);
    }
    return acc;
  };

  const text = arr.reduce(reducer, []);

  return (
    <Text>
      {text.map((text) => {
        if (text.startsWith('**')) {
          return (
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
              {text.replaceAll('**', '')}{' '}
            </Text>
          );
        }
        return `${text} `;
      })}
    </Text>
  );
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <CustomText text="Lorem Ipsum is **simply dummy** text of the printing and **typesetting industry**."/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for,with some changes it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I need some help. If the data something like "** hey welcome **",it's not working properly because of space. It works perfectly for one word. How can I achieve this

Comment: what if you use the ** to split ?

Comment: what if you check startswith('**') || endsWith('**') then it will make both word bold right ?

Comment: I've tried that as well. For example the word is "** hey welcome here **" then "hey" and "here" become bold bot "welcome" is the same

Comment: do you always have a ** at start and end ? if so you can splice the array using some logic and add concat the strings and bold it again using a loop

Comment: Yes,always at startd and end. Can you provide some code ?

Comment: const arr=text.split(' ')

const test =(acc,cur,index)=>{
  let previousVal=acc[acc.length-1];
  if(previousVal && previousVal.startsWith('**') && !previousVal.endsWith('**'))
    acc[acc.length-1]=previousVal+ ' '+cur
  else
    acc.push(cur)
  return acc;
} this reducer will generate text for each ** ** map the output of arr.reduce(test,[]) it'll work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested Text tag for different styles like below.

```
<Text style={{ fontWeight: '500' }}>Lorem Ipsum is<Text style={{fontWeight: '1000' }}>My Inner Text</Text></Text>
```

If you have a dynamic text you can use this module and define your pattern in regular expression

https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text

or you can use source code only without installation.

https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text/blob/master/src/ParsedText.js

Comment: But I want to do that dynamiaclly. I mean,I send the data to component and it must do that itself

Comment: So your dynamic text will be inside this "**"?

Comment: Yes exactly It must has bold style but the other ones have normal style

Comment: Thanks but I have to do that without 3rd library

Comment: You can use the source code of that library from here.
https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text/blob/master/src/ParsedText.js

Answer (score 0):

Simplest TypeScript version

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import theme from '../theme.constant';

interface CustomTextProps {
  text: string;
}

function CustomText({text}: CustomTextProps) {
  const arr = text.split('**');

  return (
    <Text>
      {arr.map((textPart, index) => {
        const isBold = index % 2 === 1;

        if (isBold) {
          return (
            <Text style={{fontWeight: "700"}}>
              {textPart}
            </Text>
          );
        }

        return `${textPart}`;
      })}
    </Text>
  );
}

export default CustomText;
```